# Matrix inequality with square products

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality

Let $A$ and $B$ be both positive semidefinite matrices of the same size, and that $A A' \le B B'$. Let $C > 0$ be another positive definite matrix. Does this imply that $A C A' \le B C B'$?

Comment: If $A$ is semidefinite, it is already symmetric ($A'=A$), so $AA'=A^2$, isn't it?

Comment: How do you define $A\leq B$? Basically how is your relation $\leq$ defined.

Comment: @Berci: yes, you are right, $′=^2$.

Comment: @lightxbulb: $A \le B$ is defined as $x' A x \le x' B x$ for all non-zero vector $x$

Comment: Can you show that if $A<<B$ then $UAU<<UBU$ ?

Comment: Unfortunately, we can't assume that $A < B$, even though $AA' \le BB'$. I assume that's what you meant by the '<<'

Comment: OK $A$ and $B$ may be singular…

Comment: @isentari Could you clarify how you came up with this statement, since I became interested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is clearly no. Just consider the special case where $B$ is positive definite. The condition $A^2\le B^2$ is then equivalent to $\|B^{-1}A\|_2\le1$, while the condition $ACA\le BCB$ is equivalent to $\|C^{-1/2}(B^{-1}A)C^{1/2}\|_2\le1$. Since matrix norm can be increased or decreased by similarity transform, none of the two conditions implies the other in general. E.g. when
$$
A=\frac12\pmatrix{1&1\\ 1&1},\ B=I,\ C=\pmatrix{1\\ &4},
$$
we have $B^2-A^2=\frac12\pmatrix{1&-1\\ -1&1}\ge0$ but $BCB-ACA=\frac14\pmatrix{-1&-5\\ -5&11}$ is indefinite. On the other hand, if we define $A_1=C^{1/2}AC^{1/2},\ B_1=C^{1/2}BC^{1/2}$ and $C_1=C^{-1}$ in the above, then $B_1C_1B_1-A_1C_1A_1\ge0$ but $B_1^2-A_1^2$ is indefinite.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the "is equivalent to" parts?

Comment: @lightxbulb $A^2\le B^2$ iff $B^{-1}A^2B^{-1}\le I$ iff $\|B^{-1}A\|_2^2=\lambda_\max(B^{-1}A^2B^{-1})\le 1$. The case for the other condition is similar.

Answer (score 1):

Edit:

My discussion with Bertrand allowed me to find several mistakes in my reasoning and formalize some of the results I arrived at. More specifically, I was able to show(* the proof is not full) that the claim holds under the stronger assumption: $\sigma_{\max}(A^2)\sigma_{\max}(C) \leq \sigma_{\min}(B^2)\sigma_{min}(C)$. This can be rewritten equivalently through the condition number of $C$: $\kappa(C)\leq \frac{\sigma_{\min}(B^2)}{\sigma_{\max}(A^2)}$. Note that this stronger assumption implies: $\sigma_{\max}(A^2)\leq \sigma_{\min}(B^2)$, since $C$ is PD: $0<\sigma_{\min}(C)\leq \sigma_{\max}(C)$. This in turn implies $AA'\leq BB'$. This is easy to see, since (I can prove the claim below in more details if anyone is interested, it follows from a result in convex analysis):

$$\forall x : |x|=1 \rightarrow x'AA'x \leq \max_{u:|u|=1}{uAA'u} = \sigma_{\max}(A^2) \leq \sigma_{\min}(B^2) = \min_{u:|u|=1}{uBB'u} \leq x'BB'x$$

(Note that the requirement for $|x|=1$ is equivalent since we can divide both sides by $|x|^2$ of the original formulation to get it).

Finally we have:

$$x'ACA'x \leq \max_{u:|u|=1}{u'ACA'u} \leq \sigma_{\max}(A^2)\sigma_{\max}(C) \\ \leq \sigma_{\min}(B^2)\sigma_{min}(C) \leq \min_{u:|u|=1}{u'BCB'u} \leq x'BCB'x$$

Note that since $A,B,C$ are PSD, then the following eigendecomposition is valid:
$$A=QKQ', B=PLP', C=R\Lambda R'$$
Where $Q,P,R$ are orthogonal matrices (made up of the eigenvectors), and $K,L,\Lambda$ are diagonal matrices (made up of the corresponding eigenvalues). The inequality $\max_{u:|u|=1}{u'ACA'u} \leq \sigma_{\max}(A^2)\sigma_{\max}(C)$ holds because:

$$\max_{u:|u|=1}{u'ACA'u} \leq \max_{u,Q,R:|u|=1, QQ'=I, RR'=I}{u'ACA'u} = \sigma_{\max}(A^2)\sigma_{\max}(C)$$

The last holds since the matrix $ACA'$ can't scale the unit vector more than $\sigma_{\max}(A^2)\sigma_{\max}(C)$. Unfortunately I haven't proved it formally, my handwavy 'proof' relies on this decomposition:

$$u'ACA'u = (R'QKQ'u)'\Lambda(R'QKQ'u)$$

It goes something like this: we are allowed(due to the maximum) to choose $u$, then I can pick $u=(1,0,...,0)$, then since we are allowed to pick the rotation(due to the maximum) $Q$, we can align it with the eigenvector corresponding to the square root of the maximum eigenvalue of $A^2$, and multiply it with $K$ to scale it by $\sqrt{\sigma_{\max}(A^2)}$. Then by choosing $R$ appropriately (due to the maximum) we can align it with the eigenvector of $C$ corresponding to the maximum eigenvalue of $C$, thus additionally scaling it by $\sigma_{\max}(C)$, this happens on both sides, so after the dot product one gets the squared length (only one of the sides gets multiplied by $\sigma_{\max}(C)$ though). My argument for $u'BCB'u$ would be similar.

If one can show that $AA'\leq BB'$ does not imply the stronger assumption (which I believe it does not), and also prove that the inequalities become equalities for specific $A,B,C$, then it would follow that $A,B$ PSD, $C$ PD, and $AA'\leq BB'$ are not enough for the claim.

Comment: How can you ensure that $x$ is the same in your expressions defining $u$ and $v$ ? Is it possible to find $x$ such that $x=A^{-1}u=B^{-1}v$ with the specific $u$ and $v$ you have given?

Comment: @Bertrand I tried to derive it just now and saw a mistake I made, I'll see if I can fix it, if it's wrong I'll delete my comment. Sorry about that.

Comment: @Bertrand Take a look at it if you can, see if you find anything funny again.

Comment: I can follow you up to the point where you write "$P'x$ has a non zero component only for $l^2_{min}$". Does this mean that the $rank(P)$ is one?

Comment: @Bertrand Seems I made an assumption that was a tad too strong yet again, I believe that my reasoning could have been wrong for some matrices. See the updated version above. Unfortunately I still don't have a formal proof for the claim at the end on which the statement hinges. Feel free to try and prove it.

Comment: well, I followed with lot of interest the evolution of the discussion and I am happy to see that at the end of the day, the conjecture is disproved (counterexample by user1551) and that you derived some constructive additional conditions under which it holds

Comment: @Bertrand Oh, ok I saw the other answer.